# Creating a separate module for a simple function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working myself through tutorials and books teaching AngularJS.

I want to write a simple app, that loads some user data from a json file and displays it.

Now this is the relevant part of a JavaScript file, which does what I want:

Here is my Code :

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('../mockdata/users_js.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.users = data;
    });
});
```

Now if I try to create a separate module for importing my data, I fail:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Users) {
  $scope.users = Users.query();
})

.factory('Users', function($http) {
  var users = {};
  users.query = function() {
    // In real apps, we'd pull this data from the server...
    $http.get('../mockdata/users_js.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      this.data = data;
    });
    return this.data;
  };
  return users;
});
```

**What am I doing wrong ?
And How can i fix this ?**

Comment: Wouldn't this.data be empty on return from users.query. The promise isn't set until after it returns (whenever success runs) which is async.  For our services at work, we usually just return $resource call directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `users.query()` you kick off an *asynchronous* HTTP request, and then before it has a chance to finish return `this.data` which is `undefined`.

You could take a look at [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource), it returns a promise that you can assign to a `$scope` variable immediately. It will apply the right value when the request completes.

```
.factory('Users', function($resource) {
  var users = {};
  users.query = function() {
    return $resource('../mockdata/users_js.json').get();
  };
  return users;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to do this with $http:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Users) {
  Users.then(function(data){
    $scope.users = data;
  });
})
.factory('Users', function($http) {
  var Users = {};
  Users = $http.get('../mockdata/users_js.json').then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
  });
  return Users;
});
```

Here's a live [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ers6RS6SR210XIaIIDXY).